# How to do ^= match with CartoCSS?

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap, mapbox, cartography, cartocss

Looking at the [following DBF database](http://i47.tinypic.com/1085ppu.png), how would I go about targeting the "hospital" type? In CSS3 you can do something like `*[attr^='hospital']`.

I don't know how to do this with CartoCSS, however. The best I can do is: `#poi[zoom>=10][CATEGORY="Health care"]`, but many of those "health care" related entities are in fact pharmacies, which I don't want to put a marker on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression selector for this purpose, like `#points[attr =~ "$hospital"]`.

A better long-term solution (since regular expression selectors tend to create many filter combinations) is to do this in [Imposm](http://imposm.org/) in pre-processing.